# Encode URL having India languages in URL

Tags: android

I want encoded URL having India language in query string. e.g.

http://online3.esakal.com/NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4741992566950155024&SectionId=10SectionName=पुणे&NewsTitle=पुण्यात गणरायाला उत्साहात निरोप (फोटोफीचर1)

if I load above URL in the web-view of android, i get following URL in onPageFinished callback method of WebViewClient.

encoded url from webview client :

http://online3.esakal.com/NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId=4741992566950155024&SectionId=10SectionName=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%87&NewsTitle=%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%20%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%89%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4%20%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AA%20(%E0%A4%AB%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%9F%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AB%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%B01)

But if i used following code to encode original url, i get follwoing url after encoding:

try {

```
        String url1 = "http://online3.esakal.com/NewsDetails.aspx?" +
                "NewsId=4741992566950155024&SectionId=10SectionName=पुणे&NewsTitle=पुण्यात गणरायाला उत्साहात निरोप (फोटोफीचर1)";
        URL url = new URL(url1);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), 
                url.getPort(), url.getPath(), URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery(), "UTF-8"), url.getRef());
        url = uri.toURL();

        String str1 = url.toString();

        }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(""+e);
    }
```

: http://online3.esakal.com/NewsDetails.aspx?NewsId%253D4741992566950155024%2526SectionId%253D10SectionName%253D%25E0%25A4%25AA%25E0%25A5%2581%25E0%25A4%25A3%25E0%25A5%2587%2526NewsTitle%253D%25E0%25A4%25AA%25E0%25A5%2581%25E0%25A4%25A3%25E0%25A5%258D%25E0%25A4%25AF%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25A4+%25E0%25A4%2597%25E0%25A4%25A3%25E0%25A4%25B0%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25AF%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25B2%25E0%25A4%25BE+%25E0%25A4%2589%25E0%25A4%25A4%25E0%25A5%258D%25E0%25A4%25B8%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25B9%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25A4+%25E0%25A4%25A8%25E0%25A4%25BF%25E0%25A4%25B0%25E0%25A5%258B%25E0%25A4%25AA+%2528%25E0%25A4%25AB%25E0%25A5%258B%25E0%25A4%259F%25E0%25A5%258B%25E0%25A4%25AB%25E0%25A5%2580%25E0%25A4%259A%25E0%25A4%25B01%25291

I do not understand that how does web-view does the url encoding?

Comment: try {
   
   String url1 = "http://online3.esakal.com/NewsDetails.aspx?" +
     "NewsId=4741992566950155024&SectionId=10SectionName=पुणे&NewsTitle=पुण्यात गणरायाला उत्साहात निरोप (फोटोफीचर1)";
   URL url = new URL(url1);
   URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), 
     url.getPort(), url.getPath(), URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery(), "UTF-8"), url.getRef());
   url = uri.toURL();
   
   String str1 = url.toString();
   
   }catch(Exception e) {
   System.out.println(""+e);
  }

Comment: you are encoding the complete request, when you should be encoding each parameter. Please post your encoding code

Comment: i have encoded only query String, Please check source code

Comment: I want encoding to only India languages charters.

Comment: a query is composed of a list of name=value pairs, separated by &. You must only encode the name and the value, but not the entire query (like you did), because it results in the & and = characters being encoded as well.